# Force DateTimeFormatter.ISO_* format with fractional part

Tags: java, java-time, jsr310

When formattting (Zoned/Local)DateTimes with the DateFormatter.ISO_[*] formatters I would like to always format the date with the "fractional seconds" part present.

However every DateTime object I format which has `getNanos == 0` the formatted string is in second precision.

Is there a way to force this behavior of the formatter?

(I want this because I want the logs to be easily parsable and because the ISO_8601 unfortunately expects this)

** Sidenote I'm using the Threeten lib instead of java8 itself (transitioning soon), but I dont expect this to be different between them

Comment: Your explanation is a little unclear - can you give an example with an input, output (actual and expected)?

Comment: Then you have to construct your own formatters using non-optional patterns for the fraction part. The built-in ISO-formatters do have such optional patterns which cannot be changed.